# Passing a value of more than one type to a method parameter?

Tags: c#, dynamic, types, runtime, clr

If I have the code:

```
double[][] arrayOfArrays = new double[][100];

DoSomething(arrayOfArrays);

public static void DoSomething(byte[][] nestedArray) {

//...
}
```

I need to be able to pass any value of type `double[][]` or `byte[][]` to the method parameter `nestedArray`.

What is the most efficient way to successfully pass the variable `arrayOfArrays` as a value to the parameter `nestedArray` of the method `DoSomething`, that does not involve looping through each array in `arrayOfArrays` and converting all doubles to bytes individually?

I thought of using a dynamic type like this:
`dynamic[][] arrayOfArrays = new dynamic[][];`
and changing the parameter to `dynamic[][] nestedArray`.

But this causes compiler errors if you referenced `arrayOfArrays` anywhere else in your code, meaning that you would have to update the type of every value added to `arrayOfArrays` to dynamic.

Comment: `byte[][]` and `double[][]` are different types

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes. I wanted to know if there's a way to achieve what I'm asking.

Comment: Either use the base type `object[][]`, or create an overload `public static void DoSomething(double[][] nestedArray)`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The title is unclear since a value can only have one actual type. Passing any kind of array is already efficient, but then you ask about converting a double array to bytes. What is it you are actually trying to do? See XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You could use a generic.